# NDB, Querying across multiple models. AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am struggling with querying across multiple models. 
This is what my class structure looks like:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    ...

class LogVisit(ndb.Model)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    ...

class LogOnline(ndb.Model)
    logVisit = ndb.KeyProperty(kind = LogVisit)
    ...
```

and I want to get a list of the user's LogOnline's

what I want to do is this:

```
qry = LogOnline.query(LogOnline.logvisit.get().user.get() == user)
```

However app engine wont allow me to use the get method within a query.

Any thoughts on the best way to go about this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way will be to store the user's key in the  LogOnline entity.  We can;t see the rest of your model to see what LogVisit adds to the whole excercise so difficult to see what LogVisit as an intermediate entity brings to the design.

Then just

```
 LogOnline.query().filter(LogOnline.user == user)
```

You will have to stop thinking in terms of SQL if you want to have scalable applications on appengine.  Think in terms of pure entity relationships and don't try to normalize the data model.  Intermediate entities like LogVisit tend to only be used if you need many to many relationships but are still inefficient if you have more than a few instances of them for a particular relationship.

Comment: Thank you. As you can see I come from a relational database background . In which I try to stop data duplication via normalising everything.

Comment: Would it also be an idea to store the users current LogOnline key in the User entity? or is this considered bad design in terms of code duplication? The User entity would have to be updated every time a new LogOnline was created. However, it would allow for simpler querying to find out which LogOnline the user is currently using. What do you think?

Comment: No that would be very inefficient having to write to the User entity.  Just storing the user key in the LogOnLine provides you with the query you want.  You should try to minimize writes.  They cost.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

```
# user variable is assumed to be a key
logonlines = [] # You can use set also
logvisits = LogVisit.query().filter(LogVisit.user == user).fetch()
for logvisit in logvisits:
    logOnlinesA = LogOnline.query().filter(LogOnline.logVisit == logvisit.key).fetch()
    logonlines.extend(logOnlinesA)
```

Give it a try :

```
logvisits = LogVisit.query().filter(LogVisit.user == user).fetch(keys_only=True)
logOnlinesA = LogOnline.query().filter(LogOnline.logVisit.in(logvisits)).fetch()
```

Comment: Thanks you. Is this the simplest way of achieving this? I would have thought I could have done the whole operation with one query?

Comment: In a system with a lot of LogVisits for each user, this could start to become quite inefficient.

Comment: You are trying to design your app in terms of relational db. Google NDB Datastore is more of a noSql db.

Comment: The code you provided above produces a syntax error. I also tried logOnlinesA = LogOnline.query().filter(LogOnline.logVisit in logvisits ).fetch() however this produces a 'TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument;'

Comment: logOnlinesA = LogOnline.query().filter(LogOnline.logVisit.in(*logvisits)).fetch()

Comment: No this just produces a syntax error. Not sure what the star is meant to do??

Comment: Don't forget change "ndb.model" to "ndb.Model" :)